# EditText field adding backslashes to create surrogate pair

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an EditText field to capture a password from the user.  The password is saved as a String.  It is later used in a hashing function.  My problem is that special characters such as "\" are saved as surrogate pairs within a String class, like "\\".  As a result, passwords that are entered with special characters like "\" are failing in the hash function (they are getting hashed as "\\".  How do I solve this?

Thank you!

Edit - turns out that the only special character out of the following that gets mangled (ie String class adds an additional backslash) is (indeed) "\":

- some special characters: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

Solving this by substituting a character array for the Java String throughout my code would be the correct way to go, but its extremely messy in this app.  So, I am going to simply swap out "\\" for "\" within the password hash function.